# What made these holes in my 2x4 stud?

Tags: wood, damage, insect

I'm framing up a basement, and one of the 2x4 studs I bought had these curious holes in them, presumably made by an insect.  The insect didn't appear to be still around, and the damage done to the stud is minor, so I'm not concerned about that.

Still, I wondered what this was, and if it's ever a problem.  None of the other studs have this problem.  Pictures below. For scale, The nail pictures is about an inch long, and fully fits in some of the holes.

[[image]]

[image]

[image]

Comment: where was the wood grown?

Comment: @Jasen From the mill marks, it looks like somewhere near Saskatchewan Canada since the grading authority was Central Forest Products Association Inc.  Definitely Canada though, since it's stamped NLGA

Answer (score 3):

Those appear to be some sort of insect-related holes that were almost certainly there when the board was sawn.  I'm sure they are long gone as the kiln-drying or other processing will kill any bugs in the wood.

Comment: Not all dimensional lumber is kiln-dried these days...

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the small log recovery wood has come from trees that were killed by boring beetles. After the logs are debarked, rough cut and then finish planed they are sprayed with a biocide mostly to kill fungi but it also kills pest like beetles, ants and termites. I was told by the grader not to handle the wood after being sprayed because it takes time for the chemicals to penetrate and dry. After that it lasts for several weeks from what he told me so nothing on the surface or that has a hole will survive contact.

So one of the wood destroying insects made this hole, the processing or finish process will have killed any insects or surface fungi.
We don’t kiln dry at my current mill but I know plywood is heated hot enough to kill all organics and other wood is sprayed so I would not be concerned.
Note all the wood at our mill, small log or large log, goes through the same process. I just mentioned the beetles because we got a bunch of it over the last year and that affects the grade but just a few holes not a problem.